# Create a sampling rate array

Tags: python

I have a df with 40 000 000 points that looks like this:

```
            A
     0      0.50  
     1      0.90
     2      5.94
     .
40 000 000  84.53
```

As the data does not have any time, I am trying to create a time array to the df but every time that I do it I get Memory Errors. Sampling time = 60 kHz

I tried shrinking the data by slicing it and instead of taking 40 000 000 points. I checked and the important data for me lay between 20000001:40000000. I have tried to take less data points e.g. 20 000 but still, whenever I create the Time array I get the memory error.

```
N = N.iloc[20000001:40000000]  #Lock data
N = N[0 : len(N) : 1000]       # Slice by 1000 increments

N['Time'] = np.arange(0, len(N), 1/60000)
```

How could I create a Time array without killing my memory? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you try with lesser data? and how much memory do u have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a generator of floats similar to *xrange* (in python2) or *range* (python3). They lack of float support so we write it by ourselves:

```
def frange(end_number, fraction):
    end_idx = end_number * fraction
    idx = 0
    while idx < end_idx:
        yield float(idx) / fraction
        idx += 1

a = frange(20, 3)
print([i for i in a]) # see how it works

b = frange(40000000, 60000) # no memory error
```